# Class arrays and sorting info

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm supposed to write a program in Java .  I'm given a text file containing

> I am Hakan. My email address is hakan@cs.uh.edu, and what is your name? Hi my name is Tarikul and my favorite email address is tarikul2000@cs.uh.edu

and im suppossed to take tarikul2000@uh.edu and hakan@cs.uh.edu and organize them acording to whether or not they have a subdomain(the "cs" part there other possibilities) or not and store it into class arrays of type Email and UniversityEmail.  I'm to then take a user iput of 0-7 and depending on the input print out a different set of info 
 I've created the classes and but i dont know how i can take the info then sort it. 
The possible subdomains are

> 1.art
>   2. chee 
>   3. chem 
>   4. coe 
>   5. cs 
>   6. egr 
>   7. polsci

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


public class Try {
    public static void main(String[] args) {         
        Email [] storage;// email is a class that was made to store the data
        storage = new Email [99];
        UniversityEmail[] save;
        save= new UniversityEmail[99];

        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
        Scanner input= null;
        PrintWriter output= null;
        try {
            input= new Scanner("inputemails.txt");
            output= new PrintWriter("outputemails.txt");

            }

         catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print("File not found");
            System.exit(0);}
        String line = null;

        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
        fillEmailsHashSet(line, hs);
        }




        input.close();
        output.close();
    }


public static void fillEmailsHashSet(String line,HashSet<String> container){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

    while(m.find()) {
        container.add(m.group(1));
    }

}}
```

These are the actual instructions i received for this program

> 1. Connect to the external input file. The name of the input file will always be inputemails.txt, and
>      therefore please don’t ask the file name in your program.
> 2. Detect the email addresses in the file.
> 3. If an email does not have a sub-domain, please create Email object for that email.
> 4. If an email has a sub-domain, please create UniversityEmail object for that email.
> 5. Please store all emails in the same (one single) array list.
> 6. After you copy all emails from the file to the array list, please ask the user what type of emails to be
>      included in the output file. If the user enters 0, please write the emails that do not have sub-domain in
>      the array list. Please note that the output file must start with a number indicating the number of emails
>      in the file. If the user enters a number between 1-7, please write all emails from the specific department
>      in the output file. Please note that the output file must start with a number indicating the number of
>      emails in the file. The user can enter only one integer number from 0 to 7

I decided to include my other classes info too, this first one is Email class

```
public class Email {

    public String username;
    public String email1;
    public String extension;
    public Email()
    {
        //default construntor

    }

    public Email(String U, String Em , String Ex)
    {
        username =U;
        email1= Em;
        extension=Ex;

    }

}
```

and here is the code for the UniversityEmail class

```
public class UniversityEmail extends Email {

    public String department;
    public int code;
    public UniversityEmail()
    {//default constructor 
    }
    public UniversityEmail(String U, String Em , String Ex
            , String Dep,int C)
    {super( U, Em , Ex);
    department= Dep;
    code=C;

    }

}
```

Comment: I read your post twice, but still don't actually know, what you are asking for. What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I organize and  place the different email parts into the proper arrays. What I have so far will find emails in the text but thats as far as ive gotten

Comment: This might sound condescending but, an if statement perhaps? I'm thinking the contains() method or similar. I'm assuming that both examples in the example text you provided go into the array for university emails. The subdomains are your sentinel values, so the condition is, if (theEmail.contains(subdomain)) storeWithUniversityEmails else storeElsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you only need the Email addresses without any additional data, you can just store them as Strings.

Using a List is much more flexible than using an array. I especially like, that lists can get as long as you want...

I wrote an example, using a `Map` as storage. A Map is in general a good way of organizing stuff: You can store data in it by defining "key/value"-pairs.

In my example the map uses subdomains (as Strings) as keys and Lists of eMail-Addresses (again as Strings) as values.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Try {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Map<String, List<String>> storage = new HashMap<>();

        // !important! initialize scanner with a file, not with a filename
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("inputemails.txt"));

        // a new pattern to get the subdomain out of an eMail-address
        Pattern subdomainPattern = Pattern
                .compile(".*\\@([^\\.]+(?:\\.[^\\.]+)*)(?:\\.[^\\.]+){2,}");

        // I used your pattern to find any eMail-address
        Pattern eMailPattern = Pattern
                .compile("([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})");

        // Use Scanner to find each match in your input file
        String eMailAddress;
        while ((eMailAddress = input.findWithinHorizon(eMailPattern, 0)) != null) {

            // determine the subdomain of this eMail-address
            String subdomain;
            Matcher matcher = subdomainPattern.matcher(eMailAddress);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                subdomain = matcher.group(1);
            } else {
                subdomain = "no subdomain";
            }

            // get/create list of all eMail-addresses for this subdomain from
            // map
            List<String> listOfEMailAddresesToThisSubdomain = storage
                    .get(subdomain);
            if (listOfEMailAddresesToThisSubdomain == null) {
                listOfEMailAddresesToThisSubdomain = new ArrayList<>();
                storage.put(subdomain, listOfEMailAddresesToThisSubdomain);
            }

            // add this eMail-address to list
            listOfEMailAddresesToThisSubdomain.add(eMailAddress);
        }

        input.close();

        System.out.println("Choose subdomain");
        System.out
                .println("0.none 1.art 2. chee 3. chem 4. coe 5. cs 6. egr 7. polsci");

        // read, what the user will choose
        char userInput = (char) System.in.read();

        // map the number to a subdomain name
        String chosenDomain;
        switch (userInput) {
        case '0':
            chosenDomain = null;
            break;
        case '1':
            chosenDomain = "art";
            break;
        case '2':
            chosenDomain = "chee";
            break;
        case '3':
            chosenDomain = "chem";
            break;
        case '4':
            chosenDomain = "coe";
            break;
        case '5':
            chosenDomain = "cs";
            break;
        case '6':
            chosenDomain = "egr";
            break;
        case '7':
            chosenDomain = "polsci";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("invalid choice");
            return;
        }

        // open file for writing
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("outputemails.txt");

        // use the chosen subdomain name as a key to our storage map. The result
        // will be the list of all eMail-Addresses of that subdomain (or null).
        List<String> eMailAddresses = storage.get(chosenDomain);

        // make output
        if (eMailAddresses == null) {
            System.out.println("no addresses");
        } else {
            for (String eMail : eMailAddresses) {
                System.out.println(eMail);
            }
        }
        output.close();
    }
}
```

an input like yours will lead to an output like this:

```
cs
  hakan@cs.uh.edu
  tarikul2000@cs.uh.edu
```

Comment: this is good but how could i get it to print out different sets of subdomain? for example the user inputs 1, i want  only those with art domains to be printed or if input is 0 that only those with no subdomain?

Comment: also im not too familiar with Map so i only understand part of the code.

Comment: Your code works perfectly, the only thing is I'm supposed to create a Email object (a created class) for each email or UniversityEmail object if it has a subdomain and store these into the array or list. Is it possible to do this while using Map or would i have to coveert to something else? also im going to add the instructions i received in the OP to hopefull clarify

Comment: I didn't know, that I was doing your homework :) The instructions say, that you have to use an `ArrayList`, so I think you will have to refactor my code in this way (probably you will have to remove my Map). If I understood the requirements correctly, than you you will probably end up using `new ArrayList<Email>()` or similar.